# Mongodb strange updating

Tags: php, mongodb

Trying to push some data to record using php

```js
array('$push' => array(
    "value" => 1,
    "comment" => $data['comment'],
    "status" => 1,
))
```

But in db I see following records like array  : [image: screenshot]

And it's should be like a normal values : [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you want to use `$set` instead of `$push`.

```
array('$set' => array(
    "value" => 1,
    "comment" => $data['comment'],
    "status" => 1,
))
```

`$push` is for appending elements to embedded arrays. `$set` is for replacing field values.